# HTTP/2 and Apache2

Tags: apache2, http2

Is **Apache2** planning in implementing **HTTP/2** protocol anytime soon ?

I was searching through their website, but I didn't find any information regarding HTTP/2.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The **mod_http2** module is the official [Apache HTTP/2 module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_http2.html) and it is present in Apache httpd version 2.4.17 (and later).

Stefan Eissing wrote [mod_h2](https://icing.github.io/mod_h2/) which is basis for the mod_http2 module.

Remember that all browsers only speak HTTP/2 over HTTPS so you may want to enable that too for your server.

Comment: And what about official port by Apache ? There is none yet I guess.

Comment: As of [release 2.4.17](https://www.apachehaus.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=119&Itemid=104), released October 13th, 2015, it is now in [Apache proper](https://icing.github.io/mod_h2/).